# Get maximum value for column in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

How to get maximum value for column in **mongoDB** using **mongoTemplate** object in **spring**

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are not talking about query syntex. If you are talking about writing performant query, then you can choose to have index on that field.

```
ensureIndex({ coll-name : 1 })
```

Query

```
db.coll.find({}, {coll-name : 1, _id : 0}).sort({ coll-name : -1 }).limit(1)
```

This will return you a json having max-value for coll-name.

Comment: (MongoTemplate is an API for Java, your answer would be better if you'd translated it to that .. http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/overview-summary.html), although I would have liked to see an attempt first to see what wasn't working on their part anyway. :)

Comment: sorry, I don't know the MongoTemplate, I have just gave a way to get this result in optimized way. May be some other person can give you the query syntax. But I am sure the query that I have written must be very easy to write in MongoTemplate.

Comment: thanks both for answering,the problem is that i m not getting a mongotemplate method for calculating maximum value for a field or don't know the exact way of doing it.

Comment: @AKKI : I have given a workaround where you don't need any special method/operator for getting the max value. It is just a normal query, but because of the index, it is returning you the max value of the col-name

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek's answer doesn't address Spring and how to do this in MongoTemplate.

Mongo will optimize sort/limit combinations IF the sort field is indexed (or the @Id field).  Otherwise it is still pretty good because it will use a top-k algorithm and avoid the global sort ([mongodb sort doc)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/).  This is from [Mkyong's example](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-get-last-modified-records-date-sorting/) but I do the sort first and set the limit to one second.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "idField"));
query.limit(1);
MyObject maxObject = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, MyObject.class);
```